# Генерация ссылки для iframe

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Всем привет!
Для турбо страниц нужна карта которая ставится через iframe с подобной ссылкой:
https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/-/CBucU6V~8B

Но у меня есть только координаты точки.
Вопрос: можно ли как-то на php через какой-то запрос(если такой есть) с генерировать нужную ссылку для iframe?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

У виджета карт нет апи, его можно создавать только руками на яндекс картах. Вы можете воспользоваться [Static API](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/staticapi/) и вставить карту на сайт как картинку.